# Settlers of Catan 15th Anniversary Edition?

Tags: catan

I just heard about a 15th-anniversary edition of the Settlers of Catan game, and I must be blind because I can't find anything on Mayfair's site about it.

So my questions are:

1. What exactly are the contents?
2. How does this differ from the 10th-anniversary version?  Is it not 3D?
3. Is this in English or German?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I held this in my hands last week.  (Closed box)

- All wood, large painted set
- It is not 3D, but the tiles looked quite thick (nearly domino sized)
- English version
- Retailed for $150 I believe
- Has the 5-6 player expansion in it as well

Here is the [page](http://mayfairgames.com/game.php?id=346&stock=MFG3102&name=Settlers+of+Catan+-+15th+Anniversary+Edition%99) at Mayfair.

Comment: Man, that was fast.  I mean, the question's still *warm*.  Does it contain Cities and Knights like the 10th-anniversary set?

Comment: @Little - I aim to please :)  No C&K, but the Mayfair page says it supports up to 6 players.  Didn't notice that part at the store.  That makes it a little better value.

Comment: All things considered, it looks pretty "meh" to me.  I massively dislike the re-designed wooden pieces, and for the price, it looks extremely ho-hum.  Now I just need to get back on track and make my own 3D version!